# Magento 2 extention:how phtml file work and show admin view?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions

i have phtml file and i declare in the`Block\login.php` as `$_template = "phtml path`,
its working fine but not for **MEQP2** its giving WARNING | Property name **$_template** should not be prefixed with an underscore to indicate visibility;
when i remove the underscore with veriable of $template then magento view is not working. i already use the `upgrade:setup` command but not working fine. then what i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **setTemplate()**

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate("QaisarSatti_HelloWorld::helloworld.phtml");

}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-set-block-template/)

Comment: This is automatic call when file is execute?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh yes it is.

Comment: If I replace the $_template line with this function, then it is working same. Right?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh this function is used for showing the output so anything you write in this function will show as output.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, How you have understand  that you have to use  `protected function _tohtml()
{
    $this->setTemplate("QaisarSatti_HelloWorld::helloworld.phtml");
    return parent::_toHtml();
}`

Comment: Any guidline on this

Comment: @AmitBera i have use this many time in M1 and M2 same logic is used.  M2 is using for  for rendering the html is used for template. i can't remember where i use it but it worked. but proper is for set template `protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('QaisarSatti_HelloWorld::HelloWorld.phtml');
    }`

Comment: Thanks. But  question, what is guildline or solution for this warning errot

Comment: @AmitBera Blow code  is a solution if you are looking to avoid the warning in MEQP2 standards. `protected function _construct() { parent::_construct(); $this->setTemplate('QaisarSatti_HelloWorld::HelloWorld.phtml'); }` Also you can avoid this warning too it will not cause any problem.